# The role, role service, or feature name is not valid: 'InkandHandwritingServices'. The name was not found Office Online Server

Tags: sharepoint, installation, windows-server-2016, office-online-server

I am following [Official Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server) to install Office online Server and Getting below error while running the below command:

> Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Static-Content,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Security,Web-Filtering,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-App-Dev,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Includes,InkandHandwritingServices,NET-Framework-Features,NET-Framework-Core,NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation

It gave me below Error:

> The role, role service, or feature name is not valid:
>   'InkandHandwritingServices'. The name was not found

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: It is relevant to power shell scripting as mentioned in above command.

Comment: This question is about you typing in the wrong command and then realizing your mistake, which was good but hardly relevant to anyone else.

Comment: This is a common mistake, I found many answers on google but did not find on stackoverflow, tried to put it here as a good will, but by some chance there is always someone who demote the question specially when they see the low reputation of question poster.

Answer (score 1):

Found the Issue: the problem is There are two versions of the command one is for windows server 2012 and another is for window server 2016.

The "InkandHandwritingServices" are no longer supported in 2016 so you need to use the modified version of the command in powersell as given below:

> Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Static-Content,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Security,Web-Filtering,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-App-Dev,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Includes,NET-Framework-Features,NET-Framework-45-Features,NET-Framework-Core,NET-Framework-45-Core,NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation

Also you can check your current version of the OS by typing:

Open Run=> Ctrl+R

type in run => winver

Press enter

and then you can see the current version of the OS.